# Date Format in Angularjs/ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am getting date from server via json.The json data date format is MM-dd-yyyy.but i need to display it like dd-MM-yyyy.I am used normal angular date filters but its not working.

```
{{item.date | Date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}}
```

Why its not working? Is there any better way?

Answer (score 3):

Remove capital letter from Date filter and see your " item.date " is it string or date.

If it is string then not filter that date otherwise its working

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('datCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.CurrentDate =new Date('10-30-2016');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="datCtrl">

{{CurrentDate | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}}
  
  </div>
```

Comment: i am working in ionic framework its returning "null" in ios.for android working perfectly

Comment: @VibinRejiY I think you have other problem in your code because its a angular syntax so its same for all framework so please see your code proper.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
{{item.date |date: 'dd MMMM yyyy'}}

Answer (score 0):

This filter statement should work:

```
{{ item.date | date: 'dd-MM-yyyy' }}
```

Reference : [How to change date format using date filter](http://itsolutionstuff.com/post/how-to-change-date-format-using-date-filter-in-angularjsexample.html)